# How to send a notification from web dashboard to flutter app using firebase cloud messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my new project i have an admin panel and a driver's app ,When The driver asks for permission to deliver an order It's directed to the dashboard So the admin can allow or not , What I want to do is showing a notification to the driver contains the answer of the admin, I found a way to send notifications through postman but I want to send this notification from the dashboard, or any flutter app in general using dart code.

Summary(Is there a way to send firebase notifications using dart code.).

I would be grateful for any answer

Comment: If you are able to send the notification from the postman, then it is easy to make an HTTP request from dart code using HTTP or dio package to send a notification.
Here is another solution if you are in a flutter firebase echo system, use firebase functions to build and send the notification from using cloud messaging on the trigger of Firestore events or use http call function of Firebase. If you are using the Firestore, the firebase function will automatically triggered. and if not, use the http-based function which will do anything using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to send notification

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


Future<void> sendNotification(title, body, to) async {
  
  //set fcm token
  const fcmToken = 'YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_HERE';

  try {
    var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    var header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$fcmToken',
    };
    var request = {
      'notification': {
        'title': title,
        'body': body,
      },
      'priority': 'high',
      'to': '$to',
    };

    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: header,
      body: json.encode(request),
    );

    print(response.body);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Then call the function and pass the data

```dart
sendNotification('Notification Title', 'Body', recipient);
```

Don't forget to change the FCM_TOKEN.